# Faster and efficient approach to twoSum question

Tags: python

So I am a beginner in Competitive Coding and started practicing Leetcode questions.

The question is as follows:

Given an array of integers nums and an integer target, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to target.
You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice.
You can return the answer in any order.

Example 1:

Input: nums = [2,7,11,15], target = 9

Output: [0,1]

Output: Because nums[0] + nums[1] == 9, we return [0, 1].

I followed a simple approach or you can call a brute force approach:

```
def twosum(nums,target):
    for i in range(0,len(nums)):
        for j in range(0,len(nums)):
            if i != j and nums[i] + nums[j] == target:
                return i,j
```

What can I do to make my code efficient and better?

Comment: Take the first number. Subtract it with 9. Find the remainder in the list. If found, then the index of 1 and the remainder index is the answer. If you dont find the remainder, move to next number. Do the same. Always check list for [i+1:]

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `dict` to store the values and their indices, and check by subtracting `(target - current_value)` in the `dict`; since dictionary lookups are constant time, in that way you can find the solution in one go:

```
def twosum_O_n(number, target):
    hsh={}
    # Use enumerate to get both current index, and value
    for i, curr_value in enumerate(number):

        # calculate how much it is off target
        other_part = target - curr_value

        # check if that part is in the dictionary
        if other_part in hsh:
            # if it is, return that value, and current_index
            return [hsh[other_part], i]
        else:
            # otherwise store the current index with current value as key
            hsh[curr_value] = i

>>> twosum_O_n([2,7,11,15], target = 9)
[0, 1]

>>> twosum_O_n([0, 5, 11, 4], target=11)
[0, 2]

>>> twosum_O_n([5, 10, -2, 12], target=8)
[1, 2]
```

Some timings:

```
>>> num = list(range(10000))
>>> target = num[-1] + num[-2]

>>> %timeit twosum(num, target)
12.3 s ± 276 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

>>> %timeit twosum_O_n(num, target)
1.44 ms ± 21.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule if you need indexes, use enumerate not range(len(..))

```
def twosum(nums,target):
   for ind1, i in enumerate(nums):
       for ind2, j in enumerate(nums):
           if ind1 != ind2 and i + j == target:
              return ind1, ind2
```

That will be more efficient I think.

I would personally go one step further and use itertools.product():

```
import itertools

def twosum(nums,target):
    for (ind1,i), (ind2,j) in itertools.product(enumerate(num), repeat=2):
            if ind1 != ind2 and i + j == target:
                return ind1, ind2
```

Comment: what if the numbers were `[2,11,7,15]` and target is `9`, this will need to first be sorted to ensure this works. Also, if we have `[1,2,3,7,11,15]`, it will still fail as 2+7 is 9 but would miss the loop

Comment: Why would you need to sort anything ? both solutions will find the 2, 7 pair without an issue. I don't understand what you means by 'miss the loop - that make no sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to go about this:

- Step 1: Iterate through the list from left to right
- Step 2: Check if the value in the list is less than or equal to 9. If
  it is more than 9, ignore the element. Any number greater than 9 when
  added will NOT give us the desired result. If you expect negative numbers in your list, then skip the less than or equal to 9 check.
- Step 3: If number is less than or equal to 9, then check if the
  difference (9-the number) is available in the list (from current
  index + 1 to end of list). If the answer is yes, then you have a
  match
- Step 4: Print the current index (item #1), and the new index for the
  remainder value of 9-the number. The index for the second one will
  be: current index + 1 + index of (9-the number) when you check from
  [index+1:].

The code for this is:

```
nums = [2,7,11,15]
target = 9
for i,n in enumerate(nums):
    if n <= 9 and i < len(nums)-2 and ((9 - n) in nums[i+1:]): 
        print ('Index of the two integers are: ', i, i+1+nums[i+1:].index((9 - n)))
        break
    else:
        print ('No Match')
```

Comment: So for each item in the list you do a full search of the list looking for another item - for a small list this will be ok, but for a very long list this is not better than iterating through both lists twice and compare each pair. It might be more efficient (for a long list) to convert the list into a dictionary.

Comment: That was my first thought. Have to trst it out with alternate logic to address optimization. Currently its O(n). Need to bring it down to O(1)

Comment: No - currently it is O(n^2) as the `in` operator is O(n), and you are doing that n times. I know that the `in` is on a smaller list each time biut as n gets bigger n-1 is still pretty close to n.
Note that on a list of leingth 10, you will search 9 items, then 8 then 7 etc - that equates to n(n-1)/2 which means that your algorithm is O(n^2)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to find matching pairs of values is to use set intersection between values and their complement to the target.
This will directly give the pair of values that add up to the target and only leaves one special case which is the presence of a single value that is half of the target (handled using min/max on matches).

```
def twosum(nums,target):
    values   = set(nums).intersection(target-n for n in nums) # matching values
    v1,v2    = min(values),max(values)           # complementary values
    i1       = nums.index(v1)                    # indexes of 1st value
    i2       = nums.index(v2,(i1+1)*(v1==v2))    # index of second value
    return i1,i2
```

output:

```
nums     = [2,7,11,15]
target   = 9
print(twosum(nums,target))
# 0 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Processing small amounts of data is faster with simpler / less operations on the data, if the array is in the millions it will be worth it to convert it into a tuple.

```
from random import randint

long_list = []
for _ in range(10000):
    long_list.append(randint(0, 500))
target = max(long_list)

def n_of_two_in(num_list, n):
    for i in range(len(num_list)):
        if num_list[i] < n:
            comp_val = n - num_list[i]
            if comp_val in num_list:
                return i, num_list.index(comp_val, i)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(n_of_two_in(long_list, target))
```

[Sayandip's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65944513/11420630) timings are a big surprising, my function and his run in average of 3 µs, with mins of 1µs and maxs of 6µs depending on the array generation.